# substring processing and extraction from string

Tags: python, string, substring

I am trying to extract numbers of corners from football tweets. `corner` numbers are mentioned in different way by different users.

I am not very strong with python string processing, but trying to write logic to extract `corners` values. I really appreciate if some one let me know if I have written any bad logic, or any better way to consider all cases.

```
# I get wrong corner number if it is two digit value
def getCorners(self, text):
    # print text
    try:
        if 'corner' in text:
            print text
            corner = "Yes"                
            #To check the case:  digit+ corner  (it should be mentioned as over <digit> corners)
            if str(text.find('+ corner')-1).isdigit():
                corner_pos = text.find('+ corner')-1
                nos_corners = text[corner_pos]
                corner = str(nos_corners) + ' corners'
                # if text.find('+ corners') == (corner_pos-10):
                if '+corner' in text:
                    corner = "over " + str(nos_corners) + 'corners'
            elif str(text.find(' corner')-1).isdigit():
                corner_pos = text.find('+ corner')-1
                nos_corners = text[corner_pos]
                corner = str(nos_corners) + ' corners'
            print corner + "\n"
        else:
            corner = "None"          
    except:
        pass
```

I am still trying to improve the logic, but Any suggestion to improve the logic or some python feature much appreciated

Types of tweets

```
@SkyBet coquelin and xhaka to be booked. Benteke to score, Arsenal to win over 10 match corners #RequestABet
@SkyBet under 2.5 goals, arsenal -3 handicap on corners, palace 30+ booking points, dann carded #RequestABet
@SkyBet can u price on Arsenal -1, Sanchez to score, 4+ corners each team, 20+ booking points each team & woodwork to be hit #RequestABet
@SkyBet Arsenal to win by 2+ goals, Sanchez to score, 40+ booking points, 10+ match corners #RequestABet
@SkyBet #RequestABet BTTS, over 2.5 goals, 11+ match corners, ward and xhaka to be carded
@SkyBet Kane to score, over 1.5 goals, Watford 20+ booking points, Tottenham 4+ corners #RequestABet
#RequestABet Goal and 4 corners in each half of televised games. Also, 10+corners and 30+booking points each in televised games.
Think you need to #it as #RequestABet . 10+ corners and 30+ bookings in the 3 televised games
@skybet #RequestABet Holebas, Wimmer & Ambrabat to be carded, 10+ match corners and over 2.5 match goals
@SkyBet Son & Eriksen to score, 4+ Watford corners, 8+ Tottenham corners, 30+ Watford booking pts #RequestABet
@SkyBet Benteke to score, monreal to be booked, over ten corners and a draw #RequestABet #arsenalpalace
@SkyBet arsenal & Spurs both to score 2+ goals & take 5+ corners 5+ corners in each half Watford/Spurs & arsenal/palace #RequestABet
BTTS Over 2.5 goals 4 corners each team and 20+ booking points each team #RequestABet @SkyBet
BTTS Over 2.5 goals 4 corners each half and 20+ booking points each team #RequestABet @SkyBet
@SkyBet #RequestABet Watford v Spurs - Tottenham to win, 6+ Tottenham corners, 40+ match booking points
@SkyBet - Deeney to score, BTTS, 6+ Tottenham corners, Holebas to be carded #RequestABet
@SkyBet Could I request a price on #RequestABet Tottenham to win, over 2.5 goals , 9+ match corners, 30+ match booking points
@skybet Tottenham to win, over 2.5 goals and Tottenham 7+ corners. #requestabet
@SkyBet Kane score, Spurs win, 9+ corners, Watford 20+ booking points #RequestABet
@SkyBet #RequestABet - Tottenham to win, Tottenham to have 5+ corners and 30+ match booking points.
@SkyBet palace to win, btts, arsenal 6+ corners, kelly and monreal carded #RequestABet
@SkyBet giroud to score, btts, palace +1 handicap, arsenal 6+ corners, monreal and kelly carded #RequestABet
@SkyBet #RequestABet Tottenham 8+ match corners, Watford 30+ booking points
@SkyBet Could I request a price on #RequestABet for Watford v Tottenham Over 1.5 goals , 9+ match corners, 20+ match booking points
7+ goals 20+corners and 10+cards across both of today's premier league games #RequestABet
@SkyBet #RequestABet 5+ corners in each half of the Watford & Arsenal games?
@SkyBet #RequestABet Kane and Eriksen to score, Tottenham to win, 30+ booking points, 8+ Tottenham corners
@SkyBet #RequestABet Tottenham to score 2+ take 4+ corners and 30+ match booking points and
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope that this will help you.

```
loadData = open("file.txt", "r")
loadData = loadData.readlines()


def check(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if data[i] == 'corners' and len(data[i - 1]) < 3:
            print(data[i - 1])


for data in loadData:
    dataSplitted = data.split()
    check(dataSplitted)
```

And result will be:

```
4+
4+
4
5+
5+
4
4
5+
5+
4+
```

Comment: Nice logic, thanks. Can you please add your logic for `<digit>+ match corner` case. My try is adding        ` elif data[i] == 'corners' and len(data[i - 2]) < 3:
            print(data[i - 2]) `. Will it work?